# Kill a thread with infinite loop of socket recv

Tags: python, multithreading

this is a thread detached from main UI.

```
def listenReply(self):
    while True:
        fromNodeRED = self.nodeRED_sock.recv(1024).decode()
        print(fromNodeRED)
...

listenThread = Thread(target=self.listenReply)
listenThread.start()
```

I have problem to terminate it just before i close app by `self.close()`. I tried

```
listenThread.terminate()
```

App hangs. Not really sure how to approach this. Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your test from a simple `while True` to a test of a variable that you can change:

```
def listenReply(self):
    while self.keepRunning:
        fromNodeRED = self.nodeRED_sock.recv(1024).decode()
        print(fromNodeRED)
...
self.keepRunning = True
listenThread = Thread(target=self.listenReply, daemon=True)
listenThread.start()
...
self.keepRunning = False
```

Comment: Does not work. This just stop the recv, but the thread itself is still alive and the app cannot close properly.

Comment: Updated answer to include `daemon=True` to the thread. This will cause the thread to abruptly stop at shutdown.